# Getting "Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows" error message when trying to run tidyr "separate" function

Tags: r

I have a column named `Location`, containing cities and states of the USA. I am trying to separate city and state.

When I run the `tidyr::separate()` function, I get the data set that I want.

My code:

```
salary_df2 %>%
  separate(Location, into = c('City', 'State'), sep = ',')
```

But it is not applied to my data set and when I run `head(salary_df2)` I still get `Location` column with no `City` and `State` columns.

I tried the code below:

```
salary_df3 <- salary_df2 %>%
  separate(Location, into = c('City', 'State'), sep = ',')
```

But I get the error message:

```
Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows.
```

Comment: A warning is an indication that something **might** be wrong. You need to look at the result and decide if there is actually a problem or if it's fine. It sounds like at least some of your `Location` values have more than 1 comma. If there is a problem and you share a little bit of sample data that illustrates the problem, we can help you with it.

Comment: `dput()` is the nicest way to share sample data. It makes a copy/pasteable version of data including all class and structure information. E.g., `dput(salary_df2[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. Choose a suitable sample of data that actually demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If you need help finding `Location` values with multiple commas, you could try `salary_df2 %>% filter(stringr::str_count(Location, ",") > 1)`

Comment: yes I have a row in which Location contains two commas.

Comment: Sounds like things are getting clearer. If you need more help, please share the reproducible example with sample input (including at least one two-comma row) and desired output and then we can understand what you want and help you get there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. My problem solved after removing rows that had two comma